# how can i split each list entry at the first two spaces and add them all into a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

i have a file that is formatted as shown below:

```
2017-09-02 14:51:13,959 this is a sentence 
2017-09-02 14:51:13,959 this is another sentence 
2017-09-02 14:51:13,959 this is yet another a sentence
```

My end goal is to have an excel sheet with columns for date/time/sentence.
to get there i am attempting to import the file as a list and then split each list item at the first two spaces. and then add each item to the end of a new list

ex:

```
2017-09-02
14:51:13,959
this is a sentence
```

this is the code i have been trying to get to work, but i cant get the split function to work.

```
file = input("drag log file here. ")
list1 = open(file).readlines()
for i in list1:
    s = list1[i]
    list2.append(s.split(" ",2)[2])
print(list2)
```

i keep getting all sorts of errors depending on what i try but currently its showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    s = str(list1[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

so i guess my question are:

- what does this error mean and how do i attempt to fix it?
- is there a better way to get to my end goal of the excel sheet?
- would it be easier to modify the list into a csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a string, but you've used it as the index, rather than the contents.  You need to be consistent in the way you use variables.  Look at the error message again.  It's not that you can't get `split` to work: you can't access the contents in this fashion.

```
for s in list1:
    list2.append(s.split(" ",2)[2])
```

or

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    s = list1[i]
    list2.append(s.split(" ",2)[2])
```

Apply some basic debugging in the future.  For instance, simply insert a `print` to see that variable values are what you expect.

for i in list1:
    print (i, list1)   # Check the values you're about to use.
    s = list1[i]
    list2.append(s.split(" ",2)[2])

Comment: thanks @prune . ill try it out. ive never had any instruction in python so im still just trying to figure it out. i did have several print functions in my original code for debugging but i left it out of this post because they didn't seem relevant

Comment: In keeping with your own good and Stack Overflow standards, please choose and work through a series of tutorials; SO is not intended to replace such learning.  Do include your `print` statements and output when you post a problem here.  It shows your effort, your output, and saves us the trouble of duplicating it.

Comment: sorry @prune, ive done the codeacademy python tutorials and have written a few small programs before, its just been over a year before ive had to do anything python. ill include my prints next time, ive never had to post on SO before and the guidelines led me to believe i should leave them out.  thanks for the help

Comment: No problem; we've all been you at some point.  We look forward to when each of you hits 1,000 reputation -- in your own time.